# Incorrect number of subscripts on a large matrix from loop

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have this simple codes for matrix called **rates** and works well.

```
thresholds <- c(1e-8,1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,1)
rates = matrix(0,2,length(thresholds))
for (i in 1:length(thresholds)) {
    rates[1,i] = 1 
    rates[2,i] = 1
```

However, when I apply the same idea to a bigger data (matrix), somehow there is an error.

```
thresholds <- c(1e-8,1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,1)
rates = matrix(0,2,length(thresholds))
   for (i in 1:length(thresholds)) {
   t = thresholds[i]
   prob_matrix = solution_matrix(prob_matrix, t)
   compare_true_est_sol = compare_solutions(synthetic_solution, prob_matrix)
   rates[1,i] = compare_true_est_sol["TP"]/(compare_true_est_sol["TP"]+compare_true_est_sol["FN"]) 
   rates[2,i] = compare_true_est_sol["FP"]/(compare_true_est_sol["FP"]+compare_true_est_sol["TN"])
}
return(rates)
```

I attach the photo [image: matrix] to see the matrix example. The solution_matrix() and compare_solutions() are the function you can ignore. The error is "

> Error in rates[2, i] <-
> compare_true_est_sol["FP"]/(compare_true_est_sol["FP"] +
> compare_true_est_sol["TN"]) : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

". Please anyone help why the error happened and how t solve it?

UPDATE: I followed @BrianMontgomery suggestion, and it works for thresholds = c(1) is a vector with one element, but the error happened when I set the thresholds to be a vector with more than one element, such as thresholds = c(1, 2). The error is "Error in if (solution_matrix[i, j] == TRUE) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". The code for the solution_matrix is as follows.

```
solution_matrix <- function(probability_matrix, threshold){
   probability_matrix = probability_matrix>=threshold

   solution_matrix = probability_matrix
   for (i in 1:nrow(solution_matrix)){
      for (j in 1:ncol(solution_matrix)){
      if (solution_matrix[i,j]== TRUE){
      solution_matrix[i,j]  = i-1
   } else {
     solution_matrix[i,j]  = NA
     }
   }
 }
  for (j in 1:ncol(solution_matrix)){
  solution_matrix[,j] = sort(as.numeric(solution_matrix[,j]), 
  na.last = TRUE) 
 }

solution_matrix = solution_matrix
colnames(solution_matrix) <- gsub("\\.", "-", 
colnames(solution_matrix))  

return(solution_matrix)
}
```

Comment: I don't think we can ignore those functions because I don't see the "result" object in the code you provided.  Which line is giving the error?  I would suggest using debugonce() on those functions.

Comment: Cannot replicate the error without the functions you ask us to ignore.

Comment: We need to be able to reproduce the error on our own system.  No one can run this except you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I have tried to make a reproducible example, but it was more difficult than I expected. I solved it by renaming the variable "prob_matrix" to "sol". The error happened because the variable name "prob_matrix" is similar to the parameter name for the solution_matrix(prob_matrix, t) so that the for loop does not work for the second iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating compare_true_est_sol as if it is a vector, but it's a 1 x 4 matrix with the rowname "1". 
So either use `compare_true_est_sol[1, "FP"]` or make it a vector:

```
compare_true_est_sol <- unlist(compare_true_est_sol[1, ])
```

Comment: I changed it already as you suggested. It works when my thresholds  = c(1) is a single vector, but when I tried to have thresholds. = c(1, 2) the error happened.  The error is "Error in if (solution_matrix[i, j] == TRUE) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". I have no idea about it. I tried to include the solution_matrix function here but I could not

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?  You might want to start over with a reproducible example at this point.  I can't follow this.

Comment: The error happened when calling the solution_matrix function for the second element of the thresholds. I will try to make a reducible example, but it is difficult because there are some required functions to call that function.